# How to get previous month (DECEMBER) name

Tags: javascript

How to get the previous month name in jQuery? It is not working for month *december*.

```
var now = new Date();
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
var currentMonth = GetMonthName((new Date).getMonth());
var lastMonth = GetMonthName((now.getMonth() - 1));

function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    return months[monthNumber];
}
```

I have tried few different things in my code but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any previous month this should work:

```
function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
  monthNumber = monthNumber < 0 ? 11 : monthNumber;
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  return months[monthNumber];
}
```

Comment: The OP uses `(new Date).getMonth()` so is based on ECMAScript month number, whereas this answer relies on calendar month number with no explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Just another one approach:

```js
function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
  var months = ['December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  return months[++monthNumber];
}

console.log(GetMonthName(-1));
console.log(GetMonthName(0));
console.log(GetMonthName(11));
```

Or even simpler:

```js
function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  return months[monthNumber] || 'December';
}

console.log(GetMonthName(-1));
console.log(GetMonthName(0));
console.log(GetMonthName(11));
```

Or using Array's [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method:

```js
function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  return months.slice(monthNumber)[0];
}

console.log(GetMonthName(-1));
console.log(GetMonthName(0));
console.log(GetMonthName(11));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to get last month:[jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/jc3gpwfn/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/jc3gpwfn/)

```
var now = new Date();
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
var currentMonth = GetMonthName((new Date).getMonth());

var newdate=new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1));
var lastMonth = GetMonthName((newdate.getMonth()));
alert(lastMonth);
function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    return months[monthNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastMonth = GetMonthName((now.getMonth() - 1));
if(lastMonth < 0) lastMonth = 11;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for 2021

```js
const getPrevMonthName = d => {
  const prevMonth = new Date(d); prevMonth.setMonth(prevMonth.getMonth()-1);
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB",{month: "long"}).format(prevMonth)
};

console.log(
  getPrevMonthName(new Date())
)
```

If you have a named month and an array of monthNames you can use modulo

```js
const fmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", { month: "long" }).format;
const mArr = [...Array(12).keys()].map(m => fmt(new Date(2021, m, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0)))
const getPrevMonthName = monthName => {
  return mArr[(mArr.indexOf(monthName) + mArr.length - 1) % mArr.length];
}
console.log(
  getPrevMonthName("January"),
  getPrevMonthName("December")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The month name for any language can be found using *toLocaleString* with an appropriate language (e.g. 'en' for English) and month option `{month: 'long'}`.

Based on the OP code:

```js
// Given a date, return the month name for the given language
// Default is English
function getMonthName(date, lang = 'en') {
  return date.toLocaleString(lang,{month:'long'});
}

var now = new Date();
var currentYear = now.getFullYear();
var currentMonth = getMonthName(now);
var lastMonth = getMonthName(new Date(currentYear, now.getMonth() - 1));

// For current month
console.log(`currentMonth: ${currentMonth}\nlastMonth   : ${lastMonth}`);

// For January
let d = new Date(2021,0);
console.log(`currentMonth: ${getMonthName(d)}\nlastMonth   : ${getMonthName(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() - 1))}`);
```